# Powering a Tiny Arduino Project

Tags: power, attiny85, lipo

I'm trying to build a tiny project. After I program the board, to power the dev board - how can I power it to run the code?

**Question:**

- I was curious as to how I would be able to power the [ATtiny85 USB Mini Dev Board](https://www.electrodragon.com/product/attiny85-usb-mini-dev-board-digispark-compatible/) by using a [90mAh 3.7V LiPo](https://www.ebay.com.au/i/113322553296?chn=ps) battery which is connected to a [TP4056 5V micro USB Lipo battery charger](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1-2-5-10-TP4056-5V-Micro-USB-Lithium-Bat-Charging-NEW-Improved-LiPo-Charger-Mod/182632018873?hash=item2a85b773b9:m:m0nABi0ToNRyNEbNtzeAAFQ:rk:1:pf:0)? The power is regulated to 5V by a  [3v to 5v 1a USB Charger DC-DC Converter](https://www.ebay.com.au/p/2pcs-3v-to-5v-1a-USB-Charger-Dc-dc-Converter-Step-up-Boost-Module/1663444523?iid=191674152965&chn=ps) feeding the 5V pin on the ATtiny85.
- If now, how else can I power the [ATtiny85 USB Mini Dev Board](https://www.electrodragon.com/product/attiny85-usb-mini-dev-board-digispark-compatible/) with a rechargeable battery?

**New Circuit**
[image]

**Old Circuit**
[image]

---

**Final Circuit**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old circuit will not work as you expect. While the ATtiny85 can run happily with 2.7 to 5.5V in this setup it expects 5V. I assume this is due to the high CPU clock setting. To run stable at a high CPU clock it requires 4.5V.

The VIN pin is connected to a linear regulator that has a 2V drop-out. Thus the supplied voltage has to be at least 2V about the target voltage. That is why the shopping page states a 5V (direct) or 7-35V (regulated at VIN) power supply.

Your LiPo charger already has a boost converter built in that boosts the battery voltage (3.0 - 4.2V) to 5V. No need to use a separate DC-DC boost converter here.

Just connect OUT+ to 5V and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, so the _final circuit_ would be correct? It would have enough power to light up standard 3mm leds  connectected to the pins?

Comment: Yes, this is the wiring one would expect.

Comment: @Kwasmisch I have one more [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61523/how-to-power-multiple-leds-with-a-microcontroller). Would you kindly be able to help me out please?